# What was the location of Andreas Tanis exile?

Tags: underworld, underworld-evolution

In [*Underworld Evolution*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0401855/), Selene and Michael travel to seek out Andreas Tanis, who is living in exile.

According to the Underworld [wiki](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Monastery), Tanis is spending his exile in a monastery described as a "mountain abode"

> For his trouble, he is exiled by Selene, Viktor's personal replacement
>   for Sonja, to an abandoned monastery.
>
> Once a place of worship, this abandoned mountain abode serves a
>   different purpose to the Coven in the late 17th Century. On the orders
>   of Vampire Elder Viktor, it is turned into a place of exile for
>   Vampire Andreas Tanis.

**Is there an in-universe explanation on where this monastery is geographically located?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no in-universe map of where the monastery is located, aside from being in the Hungarian region. As Evolution takes place minutes after Underworld, and the events shown are on the scale of a few days, that means it's a night or two's car ride from Budapest, where Underworld takes place (and was filmed). After visiting Tanis, Selena and Michael drive back to Budapest to visit great grand pa Corvinus on his boat on the Danube river.

Assuming 4 hour drive time, that places it any country of the Danubian region.
[image]

Out of Universe, it's a sound stage in Vancouver.